# Why doesn't this variable change when I set it

Tags: java, methods

I have a method called setLevel

```
/**
 * Sets the level of this course.
 * 
 * @param newLevel - one of the enumerated levels
 */
public void setLevel(char newLevel)
{
    if(newLevel == 7 || newLevel == 1 || newLevel == 9 || newLevel == 8)
    {
        level = newLevel;
    }
    else
    {
        level = DEFAULT_LEVEL;
    }
} // end of method setLevel(char newLevel)
```

when I use this method, I set the Level
I have another method called getLevel

```
/**
 * Returns the level of this course.
 * 
 * @return the level of this course
 */
public char getLevel()
{
    return level;
} // end of method getLevel()
```

but when I call this method, it displays a default level that I have set.

Any ideas as to how to fix it

Here is the full code

```
public class Course extends Object implements Serializable
{
// instance variables 
private int academicYear;  
private String code; 
private static int counter = 0;
private char level; 
private String name;
private int serialNumber;

// class constants 
private static final String DATA_FILE = "courses.data";
public static final String DEFAULT_CODE = "Introduction to Computer Science";
public static final char DEFAULT_LEVEL = 7; 
public static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "ICS3U"; 
public static final int DEFAULT_YEAR = 2014;    
private static final int ERROR_CLASS_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION = -1;
private static final int ERROR_EOF_EXCEPTION = -2;
private static final int ERROR_IO_EXCEPTION = -3;
final char[] LEVEL = {'7', '1', '9', '8'};

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Course
 */
public Course()
{

    name = DEFAULT_NAME; 
    code = DEFAULT_CODE; 
    level = DEFAULT_LEVEL; 
    academicYear = DEFAULT_YEAR;
    serialNumber = ++counter;

} // end of constructor Course()

public Course(String name, String code, char level, int academicYear)
{
    this.name = name; 
    this.code = code;
    if (level == 7 || level == 1 || level == 9 || level == 8)
    {
        level = level; 
    }
    else
    {
        level = DEFAULT_LEVEL;
    }
    if (academicYear > 1900 && academicYear < 2014)
    {
        this.academicYear = academicYear;
    }
    else 
    {
        academicYear = DEFAULT_YEAR;
    }

} // end of constructor Course(String name, String code, char level, int academicYear) 

/**
 * Indicates whether another object has a state identical to this object’s state.
 * 
 * @param otherCourse - the object whose state is compared to this object’s
 */
public boolean equals(Object otherCourse) 
{ 
    if (otherCourse == null) return false;
    if (this.getClass() != otherCourse.getClass()) return false;
    if (this == otherCourse) return true;
    if(this != otherCourse) return false;

    // needed to satisfy the compiler
    return true;

} // end of method boolean equals(Object course) 

/**
 * Compares this Course to another.
 */
public int compareTo(Course otherCourse)
{

    int before = -1;
    int after = 1;
    int equals = 0;
    int resultCode = code.compareTo(otherCourse.getCode());

    if(otherCourse == null) return before ; 
    if(serialNumber < otherCourse.getSerialNumber()) return before;
    if(serialNumber > otherCourse.getSerialNumber()) return after;
    if(code.compareTo(otherCourse.getCode()) != 0) return resultCode;

    if(!(sortLevel(level) == -1 || sortLevel(otherCourse.getLevel()) == -1))
    {
        if(sortLevel(level) < sortLevel(otherCourse.getLevel())) return -1;
        if(sortLevel(level) > sortLevel(otherCourse.getLevel())) return 1;
    }

    return 1;

}

private static int sortLevel(char level) 
{ 
    final char[] LEVEL = {'7', '1', '9', '8'};
    for (int index = 0; index < LEVEL.length; index++) 
    {
        if(LEVEL[index] == level) return index;
        if(LEVEL[index] == level) return DEFAULT_LEVEL;
    }

    // error code for not found, should not be reached
    return -1;
}

/* accessors*/

/**
 * Returns the code of this course.
 * 
 * @returns Returns the code of this course
 */
public String getCode()
{
    return code;
} // end of method getCode()

/**
 * Returns the level of this course.
 * 
 * @return the level of this course
 */
public char getLevel()
{
    return level;
} // end of method getLevel()

/**
 * Returns the name of this course.
 * 
 * @return the name of this course.
 */
public String getName()
{
    return name;
} // end of method getName()

/**
 * Returns the unique serial number of this course.
 * 
 * @return the unique serial number of this course.
 */
public int getSerialNumber()
{
    return serialNumber;
} // end of method getSerialNumber()

/**
 * Returns the academic year of this course.
 * 
 * @return the 4-digit academic year of this course
 */
public int getYear()
{
    return academicYear;
} // end of method getYear()

/* mutators */
/**
 * Sets the code of this course.
 * 
 * @param newCode - the new code of this course.
 */
public void setCode(String newCode)
{
    this.code = newCode;
} // end of method setCode(String newCode)

/**
 * Sets the level of this course.
 * 
 * @param newLevel - one of the enumerated levels
 */
public void setLevel(char newLevel)
{
    if(newLevel == 7 || newLevel == 1 || newLevel == 9 || newLevel == 8)
    {
        level = newLevel;
    }
    else
    {
        level = DEFAULT_LEVEL;
    }
} // end of method setLevel(char newLevel)

/**
 * Sets the name of this course.
 * 
 * @param newName - the new name of this course
 */
public void setName(String newName)
{
    this.name = newName;
} // end of method setName(String newName)

/**
 * Sets the academic year of this course.
 * 
 * @param newYear - the new 4-digit academic year of this course
 */
public void setYear(int newYear)
{
    if (newYear >= 1900 && newYear <= 2014)
    {
        this.academicYear = newYear;
    }
    else
    {
        academicYear = DEFAULT_YEAR;
    }
} // end of method setYear(int newYear)

/**
 * Returns a string representation of this course.
 * 
 * @override toString in class Object
 * 
 * @return a string representation of this course.
 */
public String toString()
{      
    return 
    this.getClass().getName() 
    +"[" 
    + "Serial Number: " + serialNumber
    + ", name: " + name
    + ", code: " + code
    + ", level: " + level
    + ", academic year: " + academicYear
    +"]";
} // end of String toString()
} // end of class Course
```

Comment: You'll need to show more code, provide more context.

Comment: How are you calling `setLevel`?

Comment: Where is `level` declared? How are you calling `setLevel` and `getLevel`?

Comment: the variable is a private int

Comment: I declared it already

Comment: Log the values of `newLevel` inside your method `setLevel`. So you can easily identify the values

Comment: I create an object wwhich is a course.

Comment: Are you certain `newLevel` is actually a value that satisfies the `if`?

Comment: @user3626304, you have somehow provided the "full code" without yet providing an example of your calling `setLevel` -- the most relevant part of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have initialised LEVEL with character values '7', '1', '9', '8' but your setLevel method is comparing them with the integer values 7, 1, 9, 8.

They are not the same thing.

Frankly, if LEVEL values are integers then you should declare them as int. You're not achieving anything by storing it as a char.

Answer (score 0):

When you are comparing the newLevel with values.

You are actually comparing ASCII value of newLevel with integers.
This is why every time it is giving Default_level as answer.
use  single quotes to compare eg. '7'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add single quote while comparing char values

```
public void setLevel(char newLevel)
{
    if(newLevel == '7' || newLevel == '1' || newLevel == '9' || newLevel == '8')
    {
        level = newLevel;
    }
    else
    {
        level = DEFAULT_LEVEL;
    }
}
```